# Run multiple jar files sequentially (not simultaneously) using shell script and docker

Tags: linux, bash, shell, java, docker

I have 2 jar files say abc.jar and xyz.jar , I want to run them sequentially  one after another.

when my start.sh is like this

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar abc.jar &
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar xyz.jar
```

but with this, both jars are starting simultaneously.

When my start.sh is like this

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar abc.jar &&
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar xyz.jar
```

Only first abc.jar start.

Also if there is a way that xyz.jar starts after 5 minutes of abc.jar?

Any help will be appreciated , Thanks.

Comment: you probably don't want the && - just put them on different lines of the script. If you want a period of time to pass between executing the lines in the script, put in a sleep.

Comment: Also, why the `docker` in the question title and in the tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar abc.jar &
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar xyz.jar
```

You first start `abc.jar` in the background (using `&`), and then you start `xyz.jar` right after that, so they both work simultaneously.

In the second example:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar abc.jar &&
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar xyz.jar
```

You start `abc.jar` and tell your bash script to start `xyz.jar` when `abc.jar` **exits successfully**. Thus `abc.jar` needs to stop before `xyz.jar` starts working.

Your second example is a good example of sequential startup, however, if you want both of them to work at the same time, just the second one to start later as you've asked in your question:

> Also if there is a way that xyz.jar starts after 5 minutes of abc.jar?

Then the first example is the closest to a working solution. What I suggest you to do is insert a `sleep 5m` after you start `abc.jar` in the background:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar abc.jar &
sleep 5m
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar xyz.jar
```

This will make your script start `abc.jar` in the background, sleep for 5 minutes, and then it will start `xyz.jar` (in the foreground, you can add `&` again if you want it in the background).

Comment: Thanks sleep 5m works perfectly.